# If you deactivate an iPad from your Apple ID, will it still receive iMessages?

Tags: ipad, messages, apple-id

I recently went on the iTunes store and took my Apple ID off of my iPad. Will text/iMessages that I receive on my iPhone still go to the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Simply signing out/removing your Apple ID from iTunes & App Store (by going to Settings app → Your name (shown at the top) → iTunes & App Store → Apple ID, or, Settings app → iTunes & App Store → Apple ID) won't completely disassociate your Apple ID from your iPad.

You will continue to receive iMessage/text messages (if text message forwarding is enabled), as long as you are signed into iCloud on your iPad and Messages is enabled.

On your iPad, go to Settings app → Your name (shown at the top) → iCloud and toggle the switch shown besides Messages to enable/disable receiving them on your iPad.